# How to hide these top bars in Foxit PDF Reader (without going into full screen)?

Tags: foxit-reader

How to hide these top bars (without going into full screen)?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem possible (I would love to be proved wrong though), and apparently they now NEED to waste More of our screenspace with the useless Padding around the search box. At least you can disable some annoyances in Preferences>General: "Disable all features requiring an internet connection", "Show floating promotion page", and "Show Advertisement".

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the name of the software you're asking about? While this is presumably the tagged software, it is not immediately obvious, and this edit would be a simple way to improve your question. Also, telling us what research you've done and what you've tried may help too.

Answer (score 0):

In common with most PDF readers the smallest top bars will need to show actions that are not accessible via key in shortcuts.

[image]

The smallest PDF viewer top bar I am aware of is MuPDF-GL

[image]

Even Edge as a viewer enhanced by  Adobe needs some heading

[image]

Edge has the advantage of reading ePub and the menus can be unpinned so as to autohide.

write a Drag and Drop or "Sendto" cmd file with

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --profile-directory=Default  --enable-features=msEdgeEpubReaderEnabled --app="%~1"
```

[image]